# выключатель скролом

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, css3

Есть переключатель. Отлично работает при нажатии кнопками. Попросили добавить возможность его переключений колесиком мышки. я всю голову сломал не могу сообразит как это сделать. помогите плз. родительский блок если что div class="main.content"

```
createChartTogglersListeners: function() {
        $('.toggler').click(function() {
          $('.toggler').removeClass('toggler_active');
          var toggler = $(this);
          toggler.addClass('toggler_active');
        });
  }
  this.createChartTogglersListeners();
```

```css
.togglers-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 43%;
  right: 13px;
  width: 26px;
  padding: 3px 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.toggler {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggler i {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #d0d4d7;
}

.toggler:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.toggler.toggler_active {
  padding: 0;
}

.toggler.toggler_active i {
  background-color: #ed1b24;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0 35px 0px rgba(237, 28, 36, .35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0 35px 0px rgba(237, 28, 36, .35);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0 35px 0px rgba(237, 28, 36, .35);
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0 35px 0px rgba(237, 28, 36, .35);
  box-shadow: 0px 0 35px 0px rgba(237, 28, 36, .35);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="togglers-container">
              <div class="toggler toggler_active" id="pole-chart-toggler"><i></i></div>
              <div class="toggler" id="line-chart-toggler"><i></i></div>
              <!--<div class="toggler" id="pie-chart-toggler"><i></i></div>-->
              <div class="toggler" id="all-chart-toggler"><i></i></div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

мб что-то типа такого?

```
var hover = false;
var timeDelay = false;
$('#myinput').on('mouseenter',function(){
    hover = true;
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    hover = false;
})
$(window).on('mousewheel',function(event){
    if(hover && !timeDelay){
        $('#myinput').toggle();//Такого метода по дефолту не существует
        //необходимо будет написать свой хендлер
        timeDelay = true;
        setInterval(function(){timeDelay = false;},200);
//сделаем задержку на триггер в 200мс, чтобы при скролле он не сошёл с ума
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону вот [этого](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel). Тут довольно хорошо описано, как повесить на элемент нужно событие и самое главное - можно сделать разные реакции на движение колеса вверх и вниз, а также отменить само прокручивание, чтобы страница не поползла вниз.